# Custom checkbox design icon in input

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a padding inside a custom checkbox to recreate the picture? Tried adding the padding and it just enlarges the input field.

```
<input  ...
        class="checkbox"
/>
      <svg
        data-v-aba2cca9=""
        data-v-98e8125d=""
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 80 80"
        class="nuxt-icon"
        width="12"
        height="12"
      >
        <path
          d="M26.56 75.19h-.12A5.51 5.51 0 0 1 22 72.81L3 45.24a4 4 0 1 1 6.6-4.54l17 24.73 44.78-59a4 4 0 0 1 6.37 4.83L30.94 73a5.52 5.52 0 0 1-4.38 2.19"
        ></path>
      </svg>
```

Styling:

```
.checkbox {
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;

  svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2.4rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1rem;
    fill: #fff;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate what you want by customizing a custom checkbox fiddle which uses svg and polylines. you can resize the inner box all you want.

```css
body {
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .checkboxc {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     user-select: none;
     padding: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .checkboxc input[type="checkbox"] {
     position: absolute !important;
     height: 1px;
     width: 1px;
     overflow: hidden;
     clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
 .checkboxc input[type="checkbox"] + div {
     border: 2px solid #353535;
     height: 1.5em;
     width: 1.5em;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 2px;
     position: relative;
}
 .checkboxc input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
     border-color: black;
     transition: border-color 107ms cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.25, 0.56, 0.96);
}
 .checkboxc input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div .check {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 107ms cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.25, 0.56, 0.96);
}
 .checkboxc input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div .check polyline {
     animation: dash-check 107ms cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.25, 0.56, 0.96) forwards;
}
 .check {
     height: 79%;
    width: 79%;
    margin: 10.5%;
    background: black;
    transform: scale(1);
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
}
 .check polyline {
     fill: none;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     stroke-width: 4px;
     stroke-dasharray: 22.7713679002;
     stroke: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<main>

 <label class="checkboxc">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <div>
      <svg class="check" viewBox="-2 -2 35 35" aria-hidden="true">
        <title>checkmark-circle</title>
        <polyline points="7.57 15.87 12.62 21.07 23.43 9.93" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div></div>
  </label>

</main>
```